# Proofs on Quantum Inequalities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Are there any experimental proofs witch support The [Quantum inequalities](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=quantum+inequalities) and The [Quantum interest conjecture](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=quantum+interest+conjecture)?

Comment: You can actually produce quantum states theoretically violating the NEC in laboratories (such as optically squeezed photon states), but whether or not they actually violate it is a bit hard to check, since you cannot measure an absolute energy in an experiment that does not involve gravity.

Comment: For what i understood NEC is intrisically violated by Quantum Mechanics because it already admit the existence of negative energy densities..I think there are no doubt about this..The difference is that Quantum inequalities place constraints on the magnitude and the duration of theese negative energy densities..i just wanted to know if there are any experimental proof about this

Comment: As you cannot check the actual energy directly, you are doomed to only measure energy differences in usual quantum experiments, hence whether or not the energy is negative is not exactly certain (it depends on the renormalization of the vacuum that you use).

Comment: Right...so there are no way to verify theese conjectures ? I mean..i read about several methods that could theoretically generate a negative energy beam so i just asked if anyone ever tried to verify if a negative energy density is really affected by theese two quantum effects mentioned above

Comment: Well those experimental methods have been tried to generate them, and they do have their use (for instance squeezed quantum states are used for high precision interferometry), but I think it will take a while until we can actually check it for semiclassical gravity effects. A great way would be to look for Hawking radiation in quantum black holes, since they stem from gravitational squeezing.